# Squarespace display not featured posts

Tags: posts, squarespace

I d like to display my not featured post in my css grid . I have try the parameter  `featured = false` in my squarespace query but it didn't work.

I found this post with similar problem : http://answers.squarespace.com/questions/18544/i-have-a-query-and-my-list-on-the-same-page-i-need-the-items-to-not-be-in-both-places

and I have tried different solutions ....

```
          <squarespace:query collection="blog" limit="4" featured="false">    
            {.repeated section items}
               {.if starred}
                  <!-- skip featured items -->
               {.or}
               <div class="col-1-3">
                  <div class="module-container">
                     {.main-image?}  
                         <a href="{fullUrl}">
                            <img {@|image-meta} />
                          </a>
                     {.end}
                     <div class="caption-container">
                            <small>{categories}</small>
                            <a href="{fullUrl}><h2 class="caption">{title}</h2</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
           {.end}
    {.end}
</squarespace:query>
```

But...even if I put the `{.if starred}` statement ..need to be after that my query has been limited to tot number of post so it doesn't display the limit amount, but less cos is counting the featured posts I don't want to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options.

**Option 1 (with JS):**
Grab the content using AJAX and filter it down to 4 blog posts, that ar enot featured.

**Option 2 (with JS or CSS):**
Create a larger query and using CSS ( hide ) or JS ( remove ) the blog posts after the 4th one

**Option 3 (with summary block):**
Another option is to use a Summary block and add a specific category for your non-featured posts and filter them using that category.

Comment: I have implemented option 2 . Do you think there s one of the above which is better practice than the other two?

Comment: It's really a personal preference. Squarespace is not famous with it's flexibility when it comes to custom functionality. So there is no "best practice" here, it really falls down to what works for you.